# Converting a subset of JSON data to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm really new to Python so forgive me if this is a simple request.

I have a JSON file that has a main index (`interfaces`) with a number of variables beneath it, such as:

```
   "interfaces": [{
        "status": {
            "ethernet": {
                "string": "up",
                "value": 1
            }
        },
        "type": "ethernet",
}, {
        "cell_info": {
            "airplane_mode": false,
            "capabilities": "0x00000000",
            "carriers": {
                "primary": {
                    "band": "B7",
                    "bandwidth": "20 MHz",
                    }
                }
            },
```

What I'd like to do is get all the information from the `cell_info` set put into a CSV file.

I've tried using the method listed at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-csv-in-python/ and it unfortunately while the information under `interfaces` is parsed the way I want it, the information under `cell info` is parsed differently (likely because it's a whole different set of variables than the ones listed in the "root" group of `interfaces`.)

[image: csv_results_first_try]

Below is the code I've been using. Is there anything I can do to focus on the data under the `cell info` group or should I start over?

```
# Python program to convert
# JSON file to CSV

import json
import csv

# Opening JSON file and loading the data
# into the variable data
with open(r'C:\Users\chick\Desktop\Jsons\home\support\bcfiles\$$5liZwDzM-Interfaces.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

interface_data = data['interfaces']

# now we will open a file for writing
data_file = open(r'C:\Users\chick\Desktop\Jsons\data_file.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

# Counter variable used for writing
# headers to the CSV file
count = 0

for iface in interface_data:
    if count == 0:
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = iface.keys()
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1

    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(iface.values())

data_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access to the `"cell_info"` key. Try the following modifications:

```py
for iface in interface_data:
    if "cell_info" not in iface:
        continue

    if count == 0:
        # Writing headers of CSV file
        header = iface["cell_info"] .keys()    # access they keys of the inner dictionary at "cell_info"
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
        count += 1

    # Writing data of CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(iface["cell_info"].values())    # access the values of the inner dictionary at "cell_info"
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately--I get the following error:
```
    header = iface["cell_info"].keys()   # access cell_info keys
KeyError: 'cell_info'
```
I think I understand what you're trying to say, though--we're trying to look at the "cell_info" key in the "interfaces" dictionary.

Comment: @user2432988 I've edited the solution, to skip dictionaries which doesn't contain "cell_info"

Comment: That did it!  Thanks so much! Now i can apply that knowledge to get other subsets/dictionaries.